# Java Builder Pattern - deep object copy

Tags: java, jaxb, builder

I have a Jaxb object that has an object tree 3 deep. I have created a seperate object that mirrors this Jaxb object. I am using the builder pattern to copy values from Jaxb to the bean. The issue is, when building A, I require an instance of B. But, the verion of B that the builder requires is different from the Jaxb version of B -the 'source'.

How do I build A?

```
public class A {
    private B b;

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public static class ABuilder {
        private B b;

        public ABuilder withB(B b) {
            this.b = b;
            return this;
        }

        A build() {
            A a = new A();
            a.setB(b);

            return a;
        }
    }
}

class B {
    private C c;
    private String name;
}

class C {
    private int count;
}


class myMain {
    com.myJaxb.B jaxbB; 
    A myA = new A.ABuilder().withB(jaxbB).build();  //error - withB doesnt take jaxb B
}
```

Comment: Try using http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/JAXB2+Basics+Plugins this will give you the Copyable interface that allows you to perform easy copies without you having to write the code yourself.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano I want to create a separation between the Jaxb objects and the beans in case my schema changes.

Comment: The basics would actually be better because if the schema changes so would your generated code and you don't need to worry about mirroring.

Comment: But if you need to you can mark your target as an XMLRootElement and use the marshaller/unmarshaller to do the copy for you.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano By the way `jaxb2-basics` is not [on GitHub](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics). Thank you for recommending my project. (I'm the author.)

Comment: @heyya99 Also check something like [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) for deep mapping.

Comment: @lexicore did you mean "now" instead of "not"?

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano Yes, you're right. This was surely no*w* what I meant. :)

Comment: You could also try out the fluent-builder plugin from this JAXB plugin collection: https://github.com/mklemm/jaxb2-rich-contract-plugin this also has methods to copy existing instances into new builder instances, and there is a "partial" copy option where you can explicitly include and exclude parts of the object tree.